# swift highscore not working on my game

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I have a function that is supposed to keep track of a high score. When I played it the first time on my computer it worked and my high score was 4. Then I installed it on my phone to it test and the high score now is always 4, even if I beat it.

Inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if(HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil)
{
    circleView1.score = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger!
    scoreValue.text = Int(circleView1.score.value).description;
}
```

Inside function to update high score:

```
if(round>score)
{
    score=round;
    let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    HighscoreDefault.setValue(score, forKey: "Highscore")
    HighscoreDefault.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: You should use the much simpler `setInteger:forKey` and `integerForKey:` methods.  You probably need to refresh the high score display somewhere other than `viewDidLoad` as this will only execute once

Comment: I update it during the game in a different function and it works but it does;t save it

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see if your save code is being called?  It looks OK. You don't need the `synchronize` by the way

Comment: I tried it and i don't think it is being called. how did it save the original 4 though